# Timeout when trying to access MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean, rancher

Upfront: I'm using [Digital Ocean, Rancher, Docker, NodeJS, Mongoose].

Hey everyone,

I followed this article/tutorial about setting up a Docker environment using Rancher:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-and-mongodb-application-with-rancher-on-ubuntu-16-04

The main differences are that I'm using `Mongoose` and `Express` instead.

Everything works as expected on the Rancher side; I'm able to scale DBs, Node droplets, etc.

However, connecting to MongoDB from JS seems to not be working.

If I hit `/` on the server, I get my static 'Hello, world!' test message. However if I hit a route that resolves to a controller method that tries to access MongoDB, I hang for a while until I eventually get a `504 Timeout`.

I have confirmed that my `MONGO_HOST` environment property is being correctly.

I have also confirmed that the MongoDB host is reachable from the IP address specified in Rancher, via `ping`. If I try to `ping` that IP from outside the network, it's unreachable, which is expected.

In my `server.js` file I have the following to connect to Mongo:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_HOST + '/api', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

In Rancher, my NodeJS application service is linked to my MongoDB service.

Locally when I launch the Mongo container and my application container, it works fine. The database has no data in it yet so the response of `[]` is valid. This is what I expect to see when accessing the production version, but instead it just times out.

Anyone have any insights as to why this might happen? My gut tells me port mapping of some kind, but the guide doesn't mention anything about that in the remote container / Rancher setup.

#### Update 1:

Adding some code from the controller where Mongo is used.

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Event = mongoose.model('Events');

exports.list_all_events = function(req, res) {
  Event.find({}, function(err, event) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(event);
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please add the source code of your controller where you are getting the 504 error? Along with that, if you have doubt on MongoDB connectivity then add following events to check the connectivity

   mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
        console.log('database connected');
    });

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
});

Comment: @Amolpskamble, I've updated my question with some code from the controller where Mongo is being used.

Comment: @Amolpskamble I was able to log the error that happens at connection time: "{"name":"MongoNetworkError","errorLabels":["TransientTransactionError"]}"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by setting the `As name` parameter when linking the `Mongo` service to the `NodeJS` service. This is explained in the tutorial, but I missed it the first few times around.

I've included a screenshot of the section where this is set in case anyone else gets stumped by this.

[image: Where to enter the name of the service]